# не работает пагинация Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Имеется вот такой шаблон новостной страницы, записи выводятся нормально, а пагинация не отображается. C чем это связанно и как решить?

```
<div class="news-block"> 

<?php $query = new WP_Query(array('category_name' => 'news') ); 
if ($query->have_posts() ) { 
while ($query->have_posts() ) { 
$query->the_post(); 
 echo '<div class="news-column">'; 
 echo '<div class="news-img column">'; 
 echo '<div class="news-date">'. get_the_time('j M Y') . '</div>'; 
 echo '</div>' ; 
 echo '<div class="news-content column">'; 
 echo '<div class="news-title">' . get_the_title() . '</div>'; 
 echo the_excerpt() . '</div>'; 
 echo '</div>'; 
 wp_reset_postdata(); 
 } 
 } ?> 
</div> 

<div class="pagination-list"> 
<?php the_posts_pagination(); ?> 
</div>
```

Comment: В настройках - Чтение - Отображать записей - какое значение стоит? Плагин https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pagenavi/ активирован?

Comment: если вы про значение, то не больше 2-х записей, если про страницу записей то не выбрана, но если я ставлю страницу к которой прикреплен этот шаблон(news), то оно отображает главную(index.php),

Comment: Попробуйте вместо <?php wp_pagenavi();?>  (работает при активированном плагине) поставить <?php the_posts_pagination(); ?>  - что будет?

Comment: Не используй `query_posts`. Это опасно и как раз это является причиной нарушения пагинации.

Comment: <?php the_posts_pagination(); ?> так же не работает, а что тогда использовать вместо query_posts ?

Comment: Вместо query_posts следует использовать WP_Query - https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_query#znakomstvo-s-wp_query

Comment: Я изменил на WP_Query, вверху новый код

Answer (score 1):

`the_posts_pagination` работает только с глобальным `wp_query`.

```
global $wp_query;
$restore_wp_query = $wp_query;
$wp_query = $query;

the_posts_pagination();

$wp_query = $restore_wp_query;
```

Либо для создания своей пагинации вы можете использовать `paginate_links`:

```
global $paged;
$paged = max( $paged, 1 );
$per_page = 10;
$total = ceil( $query->found_posts / $paged );
$args = array(
    'total'        => 1,
    'current'      => $paged,
); 

echo paginate_links( $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендации: поставьте в настройках чтения отображать 1 запись на странице и попробуйте вывести стандартынй пагинатор. Если все ок, то уже отобразите через пагинави.